# Trying to send data to a alert in AJAX from PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I build this code in ajax to send data from a form to a php file to show an alert in the same page, i looked several examples online but could not resolve.

I just want to return the "echo data" from the php in the alert, but i keep receiving only one of the messages, like the "Oportunidade cadastrada com sucesso!".

It seems like the php is not doing the if/else correctly, but idk.
Can someone help?

//AJAX

```
    $("#formulario_op").on('submit', function (e) {
        $('#cadVaga').modal('hide');    
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "cadastraop.php",
            data: $('#formulario_op').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    return false;
    });//END AJAX
```

//php

```
require("conexao.php");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
$valor = $_POST['valor'];
$lat = $_POST['lat'];
$lng = $_POST['lng'];

$sql = "SELECT lat,lng FROM anuncios WHERE lat = '$lat' and lng = '$lng' ";
$testa_local = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($testa_local)){  // if the lat and lng already in the database
    if ($lat == $row['lat'] && $lng == $row['lng']) {
        echo "Favor alterar o marcador.";   
    }

}else{

$query = ("INSERT INTO `anuncios` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`, `type`, `descricao`, `situacao`, `tempoAtivo`, `valor`, `FKCategoria`) VALUES ('$name', 'any', '$lat', '$lng', 'qualquer 1', '$descricao', 'ativo', '2018-04-28', '$valor', '1')");

mysqli_query($link,$query);

echo "Oportunidade cadastrada com sucesso!";

}
```

Comment: AJAX is not a language.  You are _making an AJAX call_, with what looks to be jQuery....

Comment: Can you check your MySQL table using a MySQL client(like phpmyadmin or something)? Are your entries added in the table?

Comment: yes, in 'phpmyadmin' the entries are correctly in the table.

Comment: So you never get "Favor alterar o marcador."? Try to echo the query, feed it into your phpmyadmin and check the result

Comment: Have you tried with "lat" and "lng" values that are already part of single record in the table? Otherwise, your code seems to be working fine as it should. (Although imo there's a redundant `if` within the `if`, no need to check twice imo).

Comment: I think i got it! The code was actually ok.  I just have altered the  "if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($testa_local)"  to  "if(mysqli_num_rows($testa_local) > 0)". But that wasnt enough, the problem is in my database. The lat, lng are 'float' data. When i used the name to do the sql query, the alerts worked properly. Thanks anyway guys. Now i need to know how to convert the lat and lng to do the proper sql.

Answer (score 0):

### in the PHP(replace):

`echo "Oportunidade cadastrada com sucesso!";`

### with:

`echo json_encode(['answer':'Oportunidade cadastrada com sucesso!']);`

### and in the JQuery:

```
success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            location.reload();
        }
```

### with:

```
success: function (data) {
            let str = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
            console.log(str.answer)

        }
```